# Assign variable to NSDictionary's values in ios?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, variable-assignment

I am trying to assign the values of NSDictionary with variables like this

```
     NSDictionary *params = @{
                          @"abc":@"%@",
                          @"lat":@"%f",
                          @"lng":@"%f",
                          @"offset":@"0",abc,lati,longi
                          };
```

and it is not allowing me to do it, is anyone can guide me how to do it?

Comment: means this is not the proper way to do it, i need a proper way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing initialization of an `NSDictionary`, using the newer literal syntax, with `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`.

Use this form:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
    @"abc" : abc
    @"lat" : @(lati),
    @"lng" : @(longi)
};
```

You will then have `lati` and `longi` wrapped into `NSNumber` objects (a requirement of Objective-C collection classes is that only Objective-C objects can be stored).

Comment: i have used the same you said but i got issues further by doing this, can i edit it and post my full problem over here?

Comment: @Steve You are better off starting a new question.

Comment: so can i reffer you that here?